# Mysqldump from a query file

Tags: mysql

I have a table `myTable` with columns a, b, c, d. I want to run a query

```
SELECT a, b FROM myTable where c in (...)
```

and dump the results. I have this query saved in a file query.sql.
How do I use `mysqldump` with my file to generate these results? I've only seen examples where you directly write the query in terminal, not using a file.

Comment: Are you on linux or windows?

Comment: @FreedomPride linux, centos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mysqldump doesn't run custom queries, it only runs the equivalent of `select * from MyTable` with optional where clause. So you could do this:

```
mysqldump --where 'c in (...)' MyDatabase MyTable > dump.sql
```

But you'd get all the columns of your table, not just a, b.

You can use the `mysql` client to run custom queries, but it outputs CSV text, not SQL like mysqldump does.

```
mysql -e 'select a,b from MyTable where c in (...)' MyDatabase > dump.csv
```

I'm omitting other options like `--host`, `--user`, `--password` because I prefer to keep those in the `~/.my.cnf` file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function `INTO OUTFILE`

```
SELECT a, b FROM myTable where c in (...)
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/orders.txt'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use mysql cli...

```
mysql -e "SELECT a, b FROM myTable where c in (...)" -h[hostname] -u[username] -p[password] [dbname]
```

If you want to redirect it out to a file if you want:

```
mysql -e "SELECT a, b FROM myTable where c in (...)" -h[hostname] -u[username] -p[password] [dbname] > mydumpfile.txt
```